# In Alfresco. How can I create a temporary file for testing?

Tags: java, junit, transactions, alfresco

My idea is to create a file in a Test then eliminate it, but my code fails

My code:

```
 @RunWith(RemoteTestRunner.class)
 @Remote(runnerClass=SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration("classpath:alfresco/application-context.xml")
 public class FooTest {
   private static final String ADMIN_USER_NAME = "admin";

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("NodeService")
   protected NodeService nodeService;

   @Autowired
   private FileFolderService fileFolderService;

   @Autowired
   protected Repository repositoryHelper;

   @Test
   public void testCreateTempFile() {
     AuthenticationUtil.setFullyAuthenticatedUser(ADMIN_USER_NAME);

     NodeRef root = repositoryHelper.getSharedHome();

     // create the node
     // this line throw an exception
     FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(root,
       "foo.txt", ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
     ...
   }
 }
```

It appears the following error:

> org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 07170002 Transaction must
>   be active and synchronization is required: Thread[main,5,main]    at 
>   org.alfresco.util.transaction.TransactionSupportUtil.registerSynchronizations(TransactionSupportUtil.java:188)

How the transactions work? How can I activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
RetryingTransactionHelper transactionHelper = transactionService.getRetryingTransactionHelper();
final String filename =  "TestSite" + System.currentTimeMillis();

NodeRef noderef = transactionHelper.doInTransaction(new RetryingTransactionCallback<NodeRef>() {
    public NodeRef execute() throws Throwable {
      final NodeRef parent = repositoryHelper.getCompanyHome();
      FileInfo fileInfo = fileFolderService.create(parent, filename, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
      NodeRef node = fileInfo.getNodeRef();

      ContentWriter writer = contentService.getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
      writer.setMimetype(MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
      writer.setEncoding("UTF-8");
      writer.putContent(content);
      return node;
    }
});
```

In Junit is mandatory to use transaction to create files.

Comment: Yup, you can use the @Transactional annotation as well (less lines of code). This is how I do it.

Comment: is it the same? I will try tomorrow, if is the same I will give you the answer

Comment: No need to give me the answer. But yes, I'm using the Spring transactionnal annotation in my test cases. I removed it to check, and had the same stacktrace as you.

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with temporary file alfresco provides one utility class

**org.alfresco.util.TempFileProvider**

It has all the API which allows you to create temporary files and directories.

If you have extensive usage of temporary files you can even consider using this [utility](https://github.com/Alfresco/gytheio/blob/master/gytheio-content-handlers/gytheio-content-handler-tempfile/src/main/java/org/gytheio/content/file/CleaningTempFileProvider.java) which allows you to clear temporary files on regular interval.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with the `@Transactional` annotation ?

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testCreateTempFile() {
....
```

This should resolve your problem.